# How to compose redux reducers with dependent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a React/Redux application that allows for "widgets" to be added to a page and manipulated in 2D space. It is a requirement that multiple widgets can be selected and manipulated at once. A simplified version of my current state tree looks something like the following...

```
{
  widgets: {
    widget_1: { x: 100, y: 200 },
    widget_2: { x: 300, y: 400 },
    widget_3: { x: 500, y: 600 }
  },
  selection: {
    widgets: [ "widget_1", "widget_3" ]
  }
}
```

I currently have this tree managed by 2 reducers one managing `widgets` state and the other managing `selection` state. The selection state reducer can be simplified as (note: I am using Immutable.js too)...

```
currentlySelectedWidgets(state = EMPTY_SELECTION, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_SELECTION:
      return state.set('widgets' , List(action.ids));
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

This all seems to work quite well but I now have a requirement that I am struggling to fit into this model...

For UI purposes I need to have the current selection have an x/y property which is reflective of the upper left corner of the currently selected widgets x/y co-ordinates. An example state might look like...

```
{
  widgets: {
    widget_1: { x: 100, y: 200 },
    widget_2: { x: 300, y: 400 },
    widget_3: { x: 500, y: 600 }
  },
  selection: {
    x: 100,
    y: 200,
    widgets: [ "widget_1", "widget_3" ]
  }
}
```

The logic here is fairly simple, e.g. find the `min()` of all the selected widgets `x` and `y` values but I am unsure of how I should handle this in terms of reducer composition as the `currentlySelectedWidgets` reducer has no access to the `widgets` part of the state tree. I have considered...

- merging the reducers into one reducer: this doesn't seem like a great scalable solution.
- passing the current list of widgets around with the action: this seems particularly nasty.
- finding a better way to model the state tree: I've had a think but any alternative versions seem to have other drawbacks.
- Building a custom `combineReducers()` that can feed the widgets list into my `currentlySelectedWidgets()` reducer as an additional argument: I think this might be my best bet.

I am keen to hear any other suggestions on how others are managing similar situations, it seems like managing a "current selection" must be a common state problem that others must have had to solve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good use case for [Reselect](https://github.com/rackt/reselect):

Create a selector to access your state and return *derived* data.

As an example:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const widgetsSelector = state => state.widgets;
const selectedWidgetsSelector = state => state.selection.widgets;

function minCoordinateSelector(widgets, selected) {
  const x_list = selected.map((widget) => {
    return widgets[widget].x;
  });

  const y_list = selected.map((widget) => {
    return widgets[widget].y;
  });

  return {
    x: Math.min(...x_list),
    y: Math.min(...y_list)
  };
}

const coordinateSelector = createSelector(
  widgetsSelector,
  selectedWidgetsSelector,
  (widgets, selected) => {
    return minCoordinateSelector(widgets, selected);
  }
);
```

The `coordinateSelector` now provides access to your min `x` and `y` properties. The above selector will only be updated when either the `widgetsSelector` or `selectedWidgetsSelector` state changes, making this a very performant way to access the properties you are after and avoids duplication in your state tree.

Comment: Having tried implementing both Hummlas's thunk based approach and this reselect based approach I feel like this approach fitted my model better and provided a cleaner and more maintainable solution. I guess the general rule of thumb that I am slowly learning is not to store anything in the state tree that can be re-calculated from the existing tree.

Comment: Forgot to mention, there is a small error in this example answer, the final `minSelector(widgets, selected)` should read `minCoordinateSelector(widgets, selected)` its unlikely that anyone would copy this code as-is but just in case they do.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the thunk middleware (https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) you can make the `SET_SELECTION` action a thunk, which will allow it to read entire state before making the dispatch that will be received by your reducer.

```
// action creator
function setSelection(selectedWidgetId) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const {widgets} = this.getState();
        const coordinates = getSelectionCoordinates(widgets, selectedWidgetIds);

        dispatch({
            type: SET_SELECTION,
            payload: {
                widgets: selectedWidgets,
                x: coordinates.x,
                y: coordinates.y
            }
        });
}
```

This way you get all the information you need in your selection reducer without having to pass along the list of all widget-objects to your action.

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems like it will solve the issue, I'm interested to see how well this approach scales as the codebase grows but we'll see.

Comment: I can't open anymore questions today so I ask this way. 

What if @Ashley wanted to delete a particular widget from `currentlySelectedWidgets(state,action)` reducer? How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

**CommonReducer.js**

```
export default function commonReducer(state = initialState.doesNotMatter, payload) {
   switch (payload.type) {
     case "JOINED_TYPE": {
       let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
       return newState;
     }
     default:
       return state;
  }
}
```

**SomeOtherReducer.js**

```
import commonReducer from './commonReducer';

export default function someReducer(state = initialState.somePart, payload) {
       switch (payload.type) {
         case "CUSTOM_TYPE": {
           let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
           return newState;
         }
         default:{
           return commonReducer(state, payload);
         }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

[redux-named-reducers](https://github.com/mileschristian/redux-named-reducers)

Which allows you to get state anywhere in your code like so:

```
const localState1 = getState(reducerA.state1)
const localState2 = getState(reducerB.state2)
```

Or to assign external dependent state to your reducers like so:

reducerA.extState1 = reducerB.state1

Then access it like so:

getState(reduerA.extState1)